# Which ID to use when logging in user from Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm a bit of a rookie using the Facebook JavaScript API, looking for a bit of advice.

What I'm hoping to do is allow users to my site to log in via Facebook, and then allow them to add items to a 'shopping basket' of sorts.
My question is, is it permitted (or best practice), to store their Facebook ID (from response.ID) in my database as a key for that user? If not, what would be the best property to use?

Apologies if this is very basic, but I'm looking to be certain of this before proceeding any further.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> is it permitted (or best practice), to store their Facebook ID (from response.ID) in my database as a key for that user

Yes you can store it, no issues. And its unique for every user!